# retrieve the information about Antivirus in VBScript

Tags: security, vbscript, scripting

I am creating a VB script for Symantec / McAfee Antivirus version no, last update etc.
For that I used `GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\SecurityCenter2")`
for retriving the value. But it didn't work in the Windows server.
But if I will execute `REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC" | Find "ProductVersion"` it will give output.
Here the problem is I can't use this data in VBScript for REG query! Also I am looking for any other option to retrive the information about Antivirus in VBScript.

Comment: Why can't you use the information from the registry?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that I have used in the past:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."

Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC"
objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

For Each Subkey in arrSubKeys
  Wscript.Echo Subkey
Next
```

Once you have that working you can replace the last bit with:

```
GetStringValue HKEY_USERS, strKeyPath,"ProductVersion", szOutput
```